# docker-compose scale command does not work

Tags: docker

When I enter the command

```
docker-compose up -d  --scale web=5
```

The following is displayed

```
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.

The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d`
starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.
```

No service is scaled up.

The OS is openSUSE Leap.

The remainder of the output is

```
If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
flag.

If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use the
`--force-recreate` flag.

Usage: up [options] [SERVICE . . . ]

Options:
    -d                              Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                                    print new container names.
                                    Incompatible with --abort-on-container-exit.
    --no-color                  Produce monochrome output.
    --no-deps                   Don't start linked services.
    --force-recreate            Recreate containers even if their configuration
                                    and image haven't changed.
                                    Incompatible with --no-recreate.
    --no-recreate               If containers already exist, don't recreate them.
                                    Incompatible with --force-recreate.
    --no-build                  Don't build an image, even if it's missing.
    --build                         Build images before starting containers.
    --abort-on-container-exit   Stops all containers if any container was stopped.
                                    Incompatible with -d.
    -t, --timeout TIMEOUT       Use this timeout in seconds for container shutdown
                                    when attached or when containers are already
                                    running. (default: 10)
    --remove-orphans            Remove containers for services not
                                    defined in the Compose file
```

The version of docker-compose is 1.8.1.

The docker-compose.yml file is

```
    version: '2'

    services:

            web:
               image: nginx:alpine

            util:
               image: sixeyed/ubuntu-with-utils
               container_name: util
               command: ping web
```

Comment: Is that the entire output? What version of docker-compose? What is in your docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--scale` flag was not introduced until [the 1.13.0 release](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.13.0) in May 2017. The 1.8.1 release is rather outdated (from [September 2016](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.8.1)) and should be upgraded.

You can pull the latest release from the [docker-compose github releases page](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases).

Answer (score 0):

The `--scale` flag works in new versions only.
Check docker-compose version:

```
$ docker-compose -v
```

If below version 1.24.0, install new version.
Follow this: [How to upgrade docker-compose to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839028/how-to-upgrade-docker-compose-to-latest-version)